# Not saved checkbox-es to Django admin db

Tags: python, django

`Django == 1.11`
I have a simple `models.py` with `task` and `label` (it should be checkboxes that can be selected).

```
class Task(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name_task = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    label_task = models.ManyToManyField(LabelTask)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_task
```

and `label`

```
class LabelTask(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

`forms.py` look like

```
class CreateTask(forms.ModelForm):
    label_task = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=LabelTask.objects.all(), required=False,
                                                widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        exclude = ['author']
```

And my `views.py`

```
@login_required
def secret_page(request):
    form = CreateTask(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        print('Valid')
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.author = request.user
        instance.save()
        messages.success(request, "Successfully Created")
    else:
        print('Not valid')
        form = CreateTask()
    return render(request, 'task/task.html', {'form': form})
```

For example, go to a browser and type some data in the form - https://www.dropbox.com/s/rf7tbbvushln94d/Screenshot%20from%202018-05-09%2011-33-24.png?dl=0
And press `submit`.
What do we see?    https://www.dropbox.com/s/h27kdqddl1ns0r1/Screenshot%20from%202018-05-09%2011-33-56.png?dl=0
We chose only the `Python`, but in admin, we see the whole selection.
I don't understand why is it so.
Thank you.

Comment: Remove `form = CreateTask()` from the `else` block - you are replacing the bound form (which may have useful errors) with an empty form. To help debugging, you could change the print call to `print(form.errors)`.

Comment: Please show your template as well. I think you might be misunderstanding the multiple select widget in the admin. The widget shows all the related objects. None of them are selected in the screenshot.

Comment: @Alasdair https://www.dropbox.com/s/7hh20d6ua1kyvl2/task.html?dl=0 - it's HTML file and https://www.dropbox.com/s/mp66yv7fjuu8rgd/views.py?dl=0 my views.py

Comment: @Alasdair https://www.dropbox.com/s/aurylddk1ctpdnt/admin.py?dl=0 - admin.py

Comment: @Alasdair sorry. I just don't understand what do you mean " I think you might be misunderstanding the multiple select widget in the admin. The widget shows all the related objects. None of them are selected in the screenshot"
I chose the checkbox "python", but in admin, I see with all the choices that exist.

Comment: The widget in the admin is meant to display all of the choices. The problem is that `python` is not selected. That's because you are not calling `form.save_m2m()` - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save a form with `commit=False`, you need to call the form's `save_m2m` method to save the many-to-many data.

```
if form.is_valid():
    print('Valid')
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.author = request.user
    instance.save()
    form.save_m2m()
```

See the docs for [the modelform save method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) for more info.

If you create a new task after changing the code (still tick python), then you'll still see all the label tasks in the Django admin, but `python` will now be selected.